# Bivariate probability transformation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Can someone find the mistake in the solution to this problem?

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables. $Y$ has an exponential distribution with parameter $2$ and $X$ is uniform in [0,4]. Find the bivariate density of $U=X+Y$ and $V=2X$.

Solution:
Since X and Y are independent $f_{x,y}=\frac{2 e^{-2Y}}{4}$. The inverse transform is given by $X=\frac{V}{2}$ and $Y=U-\frac{V}{2}$. The Jacobian matrix is \begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{1}{2}\\1&-\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix} and the absolute value of its determinant is $\frac{1}{2}$. Then, the bivariate density $f_{u,v}$ is $\frac{e^{-2u+v}}{4}$ for $U$ between $[0,\infty)$ and $V$ in $[0,8]$.

The problem is that this density does not integrate to 1, so I wonder where is the mistake in this solution.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error is the fact that the domain is incorrect.

The variables $U$ and $V$ are not independent. While it is true that $U$ ranges over all non-negative real numbers and $V$ ranges from 0 to 8, when considering both $U$ and $V$ together the domain is not simply the Cartesian product of these regions.

For example fix $V$ at a value of 4, this means the original value for $X$ is 2, and hence $U = 2 + Y$. Since $Y$ is a positive real number, the domain of $U$ is $[2, \infty)$.

If the rest of the original computation is accurate, then this should make the density integrate to 1.

Comment: Nevermind is $\frac{V}{2}$. Thanks!

Comment: Actually that should be $V$ in $[0,8]$ and $U$ in $[V/2,\infty)$.

Comment: You're welcome! If this answered your question, you can accept this as an answer.